# Transforming rotation matrix to fit a different axis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, rotations

I have data of a rotation matrix that comes from a sensor like this with its corresponding axes:

[image]

Suppose $R_xR_yR_z = R = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    x_{11}       & x_{12} & x_{13}  \\
    x_{21}       & x_{22} & x_{23}  \\
    x_{31}       & x_{32} & x_{33}
\end{bmatrix}$

I want to transform those matrices (which come as $R$) so they will fit this axis:

[image]

So do I need to rotate $R$ 90 degrees along x axis in the direction of the arrow?

[image]

Which is the following?

$ RR_x(90) = \begin{bmatrix}
    x_{11}       & x_{12} & x_{13}  \\
    x_{21}       & x_{22} & x_{23}  \\
    x_{31}       & x_{32} & x_{33}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0  \\
    0 & cos(90) & -sin(90)  \\
    0 & sin(90) & cos(90)
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: No, you need ${\rm R}_x(-90°)$ because `-Y` is moving clockwise about _x_. But I am unclear if you are asking for confirmation or something else.

Comment: I'm looking for confirmation because something doesn't seem to work with this and I'm not sure what. I'm getting a skewed view, like the x axis was rotated by about 45 degrees. @ja72

Comment: @kuhaku: You need to apply this rotation to $R$, i.e. calculate$$\left [ \begin{matrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \end{matrix} \right ] \left [ \begin{matrix} x_{11} & x_{12} & x_{13} \\ x_{21} & x_{22} & x_{23} \\ x_{31} & x_{32} & x_{33} \end{matrix} \right ]$$.

Comment: How did you get this matrix? and why multiply it before and not after?  @NominalAnimal

Comment: @kuhaku: Rotations are applied from right to left, so "before" is on the right, and "after" on the left. If you have a matrix $R_1$ that you wish to rotate by $R_2$, and the result by $R_3$, you compute $R_3 R_2 R_1$. The matrix on the left in my previous comment is $R_x(-90°)$: $\cos(-90°) = 0$, $\sin(-90°) = -1$, $-\sin(-90°) = 1$.